# 360 Equirectangular Image Stitching

Tags: opencv, image-stitching, 360-panorama, opencv-stitching, python

I completed stitching using six images obtained by rotating in place using Python stitcher class.

however, I would like to implement 360 degree equirectangular image stitching. (like a Google street view 360 camera and Matterport scan)

Can anyone tell me the idea or the data to refer to?

Thank you all,

Comment: the stitching module contains all you need, including panorama/spherical/equirectangular **projection**: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail?  I've already run an example image of the stitcher class and checked all results. As you know an equirectangular image will have 2:1 ratio, I tried a lot, but failed.. What am I missing?